# Unable to save converted file to specific folder by claviska/SimpleImage PHP

Tags: php, drupal

Library Link: https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage

I am using `toFile` to save an image. I want to write the image on the specific path as I can't write on the root of the project on my server.

I am using this code

```
$image->resize($thumbnail->width, $thumbnail->height)->toFile($imageFileName);
```

This exception comes

> Exception: Failed to write image to file: in claviska\SimpleImage->toFile()

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can't write file or you can't maybe create directory. Print out $imageFileName, see is it valid. Can your web server user write files there?